# azure mobile app not provisioning correctly

Tags: azure, mobile, service

I am having a strange problem where I go to provision a 'mobile app' in the Azure preview portal.  When created, it looks like a 'web app' - I don't see an application key, options to setup push notifications, or other options I am expected see from the portal as indicated by the various tutorials/you tube videos.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Mobile App in the preview portal, you're creating an App Service that includes these services: Web App, Mobile App, API App and Logic App.  You can use or not each one of these services.  The majors benefits from Mobile Services is that Mobile App leverage all the Web Apps features and you only pay for one service (when you need both) instead of paying for a Web App and a separate Mobile App.

That being said, Mobile App is currently in preview and not all features have been implemented.  Ex: you can't create a Node/JavaScript backend yet.

To access you Mobile App, click the Browse All button, locate and click on Mobile Apps.

[image]

You'll be able to see the Mobile App settings like Push

[image]

Comment: How do I access the mobile portion then. For example, how do I get to notification hub or find out what my application key is. Also, looking at the tutorials online, their mobile app screen has options for notification hubs, hosted code, etc. Mine does not.

Comment: I would also expect that notification hub and a Sal database to be provisioned. It was not.

Comment: Currently, you need to provision the notification hub and the database yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'm still a bit confused.  Take a look at this: [Azure App Service You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUyqj4M4bzg) at time 4:34.  On his GUI, he has an 'Application Key' that he uses for his mobile services in his .net code.  Also, he has a link for Mobile app code.  My main question is how do I get the application key after provisioning a mobile service.

Comment: Clearly the YouTube video is old news. Apparently the new ask does away with the key.